# Do "The first,....", "The second,....", etc make sense?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Ok, Let see this paragraph:

> Our transportation system needs to be improved:
>
> -The first, ...(a sentence)...
>
> -The second, ...(a sentence)...

Do the sentences "*The first,....*", "*The second,....*", etc make any sense?

Or, do we have to change to "*First,....*" & "*Second,...*"?

Comment: It would help to know what the sentences are.  Are they separate points about improving the transportation system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The first ...
>   The second ...
>   The third ...

is incorrect, the listener will be asking "The first *what*?"

For your list of transportation improvement points, you might use numbers (written)

> 1.0  The first *point*
>   2.0   The second *point*
>   3.0 The third *point*

or you might use phrases (written, spoken)

> The first *point is* ...
>   The second *point is* ...
>   The third *point is* ...

or you might use these words (written, spoken)

> Firstly, ...
>   Secondly, ...
>   Thirdly, ...

though if the list is longer than three points, using word descriptors can get awkward.

Comment: I am talking speaking conversation not writing an essay. A lot of Vietnamese students got this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about system requirements/features for a transportation system.

The simplies way is just use numbers

1.
 1.a.
 1.b

Or 
1.
1.1

or I use unique numbers for each statement, so that you can reference it later

TS-10
TS-20

I make  the initial numbers 10, 20, 30 so that you can insert another requirement later without breaking the numbering of the older requirements.